# How do I create an SVG animation and synchronize audio

Tags: svg, smil, ssml

I would like to create an SVG animation and include narration using SSML, ideally I would like to be able to play the animation in a browser.

I've done some research and SMIL(Synchronized Multimedia Integration Language) sounds like what want, but from what I can gather SMIL  is not widely supported (http://www.w3.org/AudioVideo/ states that "The SYMM WG is closed since 01 April 2012." I'm not sure if that means the specification is completely dead).

Can anyone tell me if there are any development tools or players that support SVG, SSML and SMIL. (The Ambulent(http://www.ambulantplayer.org/) player supports SMIL, but not SSML)?

I would also appreciate any suggestions on how I might achieve the same outcome with other technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [Windows Phone 8](http://www.developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Using_SSML_for_advanced_text-to-speech_on_Windows_Phone_8) is the only device that supports all three. There are browser-based alternatives discussed in similar questions:

- [How can i implement SMIL into HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137920/)
- [Future of SMIL(Synchronized Multimedia Integration Language)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300639/)

[Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350333/), [eSpeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) and [Text-to-Speech Web](http://www2.research.att.com/~ttsweb/tts/demo.php) may also be able to integrate with an SVG animation.